# python: collect files with one extention from all sub-dir

Tags: python, directory, os.walk, collect

I am trying to collect all files with all sub-directories and move to another directory

Code used

```
#collects all mp3 files from folders to a new folder
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


#run once
path = os.getcwd()
os.mkdir("empetrishki")
empetrishki = path + "/empetrishki" #destination dir
print(path)
print(empetrishki)

#recursive collection
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=True):
    for name in files:
        filePath = Path(name)
        if filePath.suffix.lower() == ".mp3":
            print(filePath)
            os.path.join
            filePath.rename(empetrishki.joinpath(filePath))
```

I have trouble with the last line of moving files: `filePath.rename()` nor `shutil.move` nor `joinpath()` have worked for me. Maybe that's because I am trying to change the element in the tuple - the output from `os.walk`

Similar code works with `os.scandir` but this would collect files only in the current directory

How can I fix that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pathlib.Path(name) that doesn't mean that something exists called name. Hence, you do need to be careful that you have a full path, or relative path, and you need to make sure to resolve those. In particular I am noting that you don't change your working directory and have a line like this:

```
filePath = Path(name)
```

This means that while you may be walking down the directory, your working directory may not be changing. You should make your path from the root and the name, it is also a good idea to resolve so that the full path is known.

```
filePath = Path(root).joinpath(name).resolve()
```

You can also place the Path(root) outside the inner loop as well. Now you have an absolute path from '/home/' to the filename. Hence, you should be able to rename with .rename(), like:

```
filePath.rename(x.parent.joinpath(newname))
#Or to another directory
filePath.rename(other_dir.joinpath(newname))
```

All together:

```
from pathlib import os, Path

empetrishki = Path.cwd().joinpath("empetrishki").resolve()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=True):
    root = Path(root).resolve()
    for name in files:
        file = root.joinpath(name)
        if file.suffix.lower() == ".mp3":
            file.rename(empetrishki.joinpath(file.name))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It hasn't worked right away because of the last line renaming/moving which. I figured it was because of giving the `.joinpath` full PossixPath of a file instead of just it's name with suffix:

`file.rename(empetrishki.joinpath(name))`

Comment: Ah, right. I can fix that. You could also do file.name as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=True):
    if root == empetrishki:
        continue  # skip the destination dir
    for name in files:
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(name)
        if extension.lower() == ".mp3":
            oldpath = os.path.join(root, name)
            newpath = os.path.join(empetrishki, name)
            print(oldpath)
            shutil.move(oldpath, newpath)
```

This is what I suggest. Your code is running on the current directory, and the file is at the path `os.path.join(root, name)` and you need to provide such path to your move function.

Besides, I would also suggest to use `os.path.splitext` for extracting the file extension. More pythonic. And also you might want to skip scanning your target directory.

Comment: I would highly recommend to stick with the pathlib module instead of os.path.

Comment: Thanks that worked too! I saved `skip the dir` part